# Pandas Dataframe Groupby multiple columns then sum

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, aggregate-functions

Assume the following for each Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

In Pandas, if I have a dataframe of 2 columns, one of which is an array of numbers, I can sum over the values of the array to get a single array.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar'], 'numbers' : [np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]),np.array([2, 4, 2, 4]),np.array([2, 3, 4, 5]),np.array([1, 3, 5, 7])]} )
df['arrays'].sum()
```

I can even group by the first column and then sum over the second column to get sums for each group:

```
grpA = df.groupby('A')
grpA.sum()
```

However, if I have multiple other columns besides the array column, say 2 other columns, then I get a `ValueError: Function does not reduce` when trying to group by the first two columns and sum over the array column:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar'],'B': ['la', 'la', 'al', 'al'],'numbers' : [np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]),np.array([2, 4, 2, 4]),np.array([2, 3, 4, 5]),np.array([1, 3, 5, 7])]} )
grpAB = df2.groupby(['A','B'])
grpAB.sum()
```

In SQL, the following would work if I could sum over arrays:

```
select A, B, sum(numbers)
    from df2
    group by A, B
```

Is there a way to successfully group by multiple columns and sum over the last array column in Pandas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `lambda` expression.  The `iat` expression takes the scalar value of the first element in the Series (here just the list of numbers), and then sums the results.

```
>>> df2.groupby(['A', 'B']).numbers.apply(lambda x: x.iat[0].sum())

A    B 
bar  al    16
     la    12
foo  al    14
     la    10
Name: numbers, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar'],'B': ['la', 'la', 'al', 'al'],'numbers' : [np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]),np.array([2, 4, 2, 4]),np.array([2, 3, 4, 5]),np.array([1, 3, 5, 7])]} )

grouped = df2.groupby(['A','B'])

#set up empty arrays to append data from below loop
array=[]
index=[]

#loop through the grouped data and sum up the array numbers 
for i,j in grouped:
    array.append({'numbers':j.numbers.sum()})
    index.append(i)

#put summed array back into a dataframe 
print pd.DataFrame((array),index=index)
```

Comment: Hi Tom, it doesn't look like this works. It outputs just one array and is equivalent to df2['array'].sum(). But you have given me an idea with apply. Let me see if I can figure something out.

Comment: Hi, sorry I misunderstood this problem - I have edited the answer and should be close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar'],'B': ['la', 'la', 'al', 'al'],'numbers' : [np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]),np.array([2, 4, 2, 4]),np.array([2, 3, 4, 5]),np.array([1, 3, 5, 7])]} )


Out[42]:
     A   B    numbers
0   foo la  [1, 2, 3, 4]
1   bar la  [2, 4, 2, 4]
2   foo al  [2, 3, 4, 5]
3   bar al  [1, 3, 5, 7]

grpAB = df2.groupby(['A','B'])
res = grpAB.apply(lambda x : x.numbers.sum())


Out[43]:
A    B 
bar  al    [1, 3, 5, 7]
     la    [2, 4, 2, 4]
foo  al    [2, 3, 4, 5]
     la    [1, 2, 3, 4]
dtype: object

pd.DataFrame(res , columns = ['numbers'])


Out[44]:
numbers
A   B   
bar al  [1, 3, 5, 7]
    la  [2, 4, 2, 4]
foo al  [2, 3, 4, 5]
    la  [1, 2, 3, 4]
# if you want to reset the index
pd.DataFrame(res , columns = ['numbers']).reset_index()


Out[45]:
     A  B   numbers
0   bar al  [1, 3, 5, 7]
1   bar la  [2, 4, 2, 4]
2   foo al  [2, 3, 4, 5]
3   foo la  [1, 2, 3, 4]
```